# Ruby front-end and PHP back-end for a web app?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I'm designing a web application.

I was wondering if it was feasible to design a ruby front end, which stores and retrieves data to display to the user.

Then develop a php backend which listens to the database for changes, and depending on what was changed, performs some actions and updates the database.

Any thoughts on this type of implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly feasible and may or may not make sense for your application. Research "n-tier architecture". For example: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/08/n-tier-architecture-introduction.html

Comment: why do some people want to have ruby as front end and backend in some other languages??
Why opting ruby as front end rather than with HTML,css,js?? Anyway the browser will render it as html only?? Whats the basic idea behind doing that way??
I am sorry if I am asking you the wrong question. I just need to clarify it rather than keeping it as doubt

Comment: Any number of reasons. Because technology A scales better for front-end servers while technology B is faster for backend processes, because it's easier to put together some HTML in technology A while technology B has much better concurrency handling on the backend and you need that, because your front-end designer guys are really familiar with technology A but the backend guys feel really comfortable with technology B...

Comment: I am really confused.. Please tell me what do you mean exactly when people say front end in ROR.?? What my understanding is that basically writing ROR codes for textboxes, checkboxes, etc (everything related to front end) instead of pure HTML.. Is that correct.. I am sorry if I am asking you wrong question because I thought of clarifying it instead of keeping as doubt in my mind..

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is sufficient to handle front end and back end,why you want to mix 2 language if it's not required,

In rails there are callbacks which will help you if something change in table field you can do what you want.